# Get array(from Realm) of custom class grouped by some specific property

Tags: swift, realm, nsarray, grouping

My Model looks like this-

```
class Model: Object {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var sessionId: String?

    static var all: [Model] {
        get {
            // Get all and return them
        }
    }

    static func getAllModelsGroupedBySessionId() -> [[Model]] {
        let all = Model.all

        var set = Set<String>()
        for element in all {
            if let sessionId = element.sessionId {
                set.insert(sessionId)
            }
        }

        let uniqueSessionIds = set.map { $0 }

        var array: [[Model]] = []

        for sessionId in uniqueSessionIds {
            var arr:[Model] = []
            for element in all {
                if element.sessionId == sessionId {
                    arr.append(element)
                }
            }
            array.append(arr)
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

My `po Model.all` is:

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : Model {
    id = one;
    sessionId = A;
}
  ▿ 1 : Model {
    id = two;
    sessionId = B;
}
  ▿ 2 : Model {
    id = three;
    sessionId = B;
}
```

And `po Model. getAllModelsGroupedBySessionId()`

```
▿ 2 element
  ▿ 0 : 1 elements
    ▿ 0 : Model {
    id = one;
    sessionId = A;
  }
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : Model {
    id = two;
    sessionId = B;
  }
    ▿ 1 : Model {
    id = three;
    sessionId = B;
  }
```

So my `getAllModelsGroupedBySessionId` works great but I want to if `Realm` or `Array` provides some api for the same work.

```
arrayOfArrays = Model. getAllModelsGroupedBySessionId()
```

An example is-

```
[[allmodelsWithSessionIdAsOne], [allmodelsWithSessionIdAsTwo]]
```

I don't want to sort them, I want an "array of arrays", where there is an array of, array of elements of with same session id.

I want to later populate that array in `UICollectionView`, where `arrayOfarrays.count` is number of section and `arrayOfArray[section].count` is number of item in that section.

Comment: So you basically want to retrieve all `Model` objects from Realm and sort them by `sessionId`?

Comment: I have updated the question, @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm makes it easy to use relations for grouping. Because Realm is very cheap to fetch relations unlike SQL. In other words, instead of grouping when fetching, save it in a grouped state in advance.

When saving the Model object, You can add code to do grouping at the same time like the following.

```
let model = Model()
model.sessionId = "..."
...
```

`Group` and `addModel()` implemetation is here:

```
Group.addModel(model)

class Model: Object {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var sessionId: String?
}

class Group: Object {
    dynamic var sessionId: String?
    let models = List<Model>()

    static override func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "sessionId"
    }

    static func addModel(_ model: Model) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        if let sessionId = model.sessionId {
            if let group = realm.object(ofType: Group.self, forPrimaryKey: sessionId) {
                try! realm.write {
                    group.models.append(model)
                }
            } else {
                let group = Group()
                group.sessionId = sessionId
                group.models.append(model)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(group)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can get same grouped data structure you mentioned, just fetch `Group` objects.

```
realm.objects(Group.self)
```

Comment: I guess I don't need `dynamic var sessionId: String?` in `Model` class. Am I right?

Comment: @NikhilManapure No. Most Realm properties require dynamic attribute. Because Realm offers lazy loading. So it needs dynamic dispatch. See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes